# Simple python function made simple

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given an array containing some strings, return an array containing the length of those strings.

```
  x = ["andrew", "jake","linda","chris"]
  def length_array(input_array):
      w = []
      for e in input_array:
          w.append(len(e))
      return w
```

how do I make this into a list comprehension?

Comment: This is one of the places where I prefer `map` over `list comprehension`, even if its un-pythonic. In your case: `result = map(len, arr)` – **even simple** ;)

Comment: Seems kind of like ruby, which I'm also learning concurrently.

Answer (score 4):

Since the title speaks about simplifying the given code, *I'll go against what's considered "pythonic"* to have a simpler and a more readable code.

In your case, it can be something as simple as:

```
result = map(len, arr)
```

Output:

```
>>> map(len, ["test", "test123","blah"])
[4, 7, 4]
```

Comment: I realize the tag is `python2.7`, but on the off-chance a python3 coder sees this, they would need to wrap this in a `list` call to get identical output since `map` returns a *map object* and not a *list*: `result = list(map(len, arr))`. Of course, you would only need to do this if you truely needed a `list`.  If you just needed to iterate then leaving out the `list` call is better.

Answer (score 3):

try like this:

```
[len(x) for x in ["andrew", "jake","linda","chris"]]
```

so in you function it will look like this:

```
def length_array(input_array):
    return [len(x) for x in input_array]
```

demo:

```
>>> length_array(["andrew", "jake","linda","chris"])
[6, 4, 5, 5]
```

Comment: i dident got you, but yes it is list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ["andrew", "jake","linda","chris"]

def length_array(input_array):
    w = [len(e) for e in input_array]
    return w

print length_array(x)
```

Comment: You could explain it a little.